# How do I get XML values and then output them into htm files using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, ajax

Can anyone tell me or provide a full (but simple) example on how to get the value of an XML node and plot (output) it into a specific HTML element.

I have spent hours trying to look this up, but nothing works for me or examples are incomplete.

Also, note that I neither require nor desire use of the ".each" method or any loops.  I just want to singularly grab one node value and put it into one html element, however I would love to have an example of what is in both files (xml and javascript), as well as how to open the xml document.  I have seen examples of opening the xml document, but they are different from eachother so there is no way for me to know which one actually works.

I have also done some testing on this, but can't seem to get it to plot anything.

Comment: Can you show what code you tried? It helps everyone

Comment: It doesn't matter, I've tried several things, I just need a simple example, if that's ok.

Comment: We do get notifications about your comments and some of us who are committed to trying to help you with your question might not exactly appreciate the fact that you think we just ditch you if we don't immediately help you. It's hard for us to help when you provide absolutely no code at all (I know you said you've tried several things but it helps us to see what you've tried). I'm still looking into your question and I'm sure others have as well so please be patient. If we really don't know, then I'm sorry but it's no reason to take it out on the community.

Comment: See what I mean? "take it out on the community" "might not exactly appreciate it?"  You take the time to post when your butt is hurt, and that's about it... You don't need code to suggest the best approach or example.  You just don't...

Comment: See below, they did all that without any code example! Imagine that!  If I had a code example to post that was in any way relevant to help the fine people of this community help me, believe me I wouldn't hesitate to post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main thing you need to understand is how the DOM works. If you do not know how the DOM works, you can find some info [here](http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/default.asp)

In essence you're dealing with parent tags and children tags. With XML, you need to extract that information and from there you can do whatever you like.

If you go [here](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_nodes_get.asp) to the left handside bar there are lots of examples and tutorials on how to manipulate XML DOM nodes

Here are just a couple things to know though (my professor taught me this and they're useful tips)

1. You can't use ids or classes. Instead you should be getting the XML nodes with

   `var elements = node.getElementsByTagName("tagname");`
2. You can't use innerHTML to get the text inside a node. You could in HTML, but not for XML. For that you have to use

   `var text = node.firstChild.nodeValue;`
3. You can't use `.attributeName` to get an Attribute. You need to use

   `var attrValue = node.getAttribute("attrName");`

Hope this helps. If you're still struggling, just ask.

Alright well I've been trying to work with the examples on w3schools and I hope this helps. If it doesn't just ask:

Go to this [example](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_responsexml)

I'm going to try to walkthrough this example but you should be getting a general idea of what's going on. They have an XML file known as [cd_catalog.xml](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/cd_catalog.xml) with all the information they need. When they press the button it simply displays all that information in an HTML format. If you look at the HTML code before and after you can see that the `myDiv` gets populated with all the artists in the xml file.

Now let's look at the code.

```
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
var txt,x,i;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
    txt="";
    x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("ARTIST");
    for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
      {
      txt=txt + x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br />";
      }
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=txt;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","cd_catalog.xml",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Some key things to point out. Step-by-step they have a function so when the document is fully loaded, and the code has been sent (this is checked by `xmlhttp.status==200`) he's going to pull all the xml data from cd_catalog.xml and store it into `xmlDoc` by getting the `xmlhttp.responseXML`

So now `xmlDoc` has all the information from cd_catalog.xml stored in a convenient variable. From there, he uses `xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("ARTIST");` to get an array of ALL the artists in the xml file and nothing else. He names this array x.

Now he goes through this giant array known as x and for each index `i` (represented as x[i]) he gets the [childNodes](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/prop_element_childnodes.asp) which returns an array with only one thing inside it (the text) which is why he refers to `childNodes[0]` index and he gets the `.nodeValue` of it. So NOW he has the text that was originally stored in the  xml file in a variable called `txt` and he simply adds a `</br>` tag and whatever else HTML he wants and puts it via `document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML` so that it is translated into HTML format. This process repeats for each ARTIST tag in the xml file.

I hope this helps. If you're still confused, let us know. And this does require you to know the xml file you're handling and where it is.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I guess I am having trouble loading the xml or something. Every example I see refers to some variable that is not defined in the example, so I have no idea what it's supposed to contain, or even what type it is.

I don't mind using jQuery but I haven't had much success with the $.ajax call (well, I suppose I haven't had much success with any of it, lol, so I suppose it doesn't matter, as long as it works, right?).

Comment: Also, W3Schools' method (not using ajax) suggests that you need to load the xml file and then an xml string into string, but their method simply doesn't work for me.  Is there dumb version of loading an xml string necessary, at all?

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example and a walkthrough. I hope it helps. If not just post your questions.

Comment: Hey, thank you! very helpful, I spent too much time wondering what some little things were in some of the online code examples that were never explained.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: did this help you solve your problem? if it did I would appreciate it if you accepted my answer :D

Answer (score 1):

Well, You can use an Ajax call to get the file to read, and in the success callback you can manipulate the data received from the file...

Assuming that the xml is like this:

```
<nodeYouWant simpleAttr="JustAnExample">Text inside Node</nodeYouWant>
```

To get the XML node, you can use:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "pathToXML.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(data){

        //this gets a node
        var node = data.getElementsByTagName("nodeYouWant");

        //this gets an attribute from the node you just got
        var attr = node.getAttribute("simpleAttr");


       //To put that attr on a html block:
       $(selector).html(attr);

      //or if you want the text content of the node do:
      var nodeText = $(node).text();
      $(selector).html(nodeText);

    }
});
```

the $(selector) it's a jQuery way to define the html block you want to put the text...

Example:

```
<div id="myID" class="myClass"></div>
```

selector can be $(".myClass") or $("#myID")

See [selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) for more information.

I hope this help.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but what is 'data'?  it is for me, as of yet, undefined, so I don't know what that is.

Comment: tried with document.getElementsByTagName("desiredNode");

But that didn't work either.  Still unclear as to what data is in your example.

Comment: In your example, what is 'data'?

Comment: VoidKing, sorry for taking too long to answer you, data is what you get from an Ajax call after reading the file... [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).... I'll edit the answer with an example